# jQuery UI - Sortable flies in from top

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, fuelux

**UPDATE**

- Included some sample code and screenshots
- Problem **only** happens in Chrome and Chromium, not Firefox

**While hovering and clicking on a sortable row**

[image]

**Within milliseconds of moving the mouse (dragging row), the same row "flies in" from the top**

[image]

I am  experiencing a **very** odd issue with `jquery UI sortables` while using Twitter Bootstrap and a table.

I've made the table rows within `tbody` sortable in order for the user to change the order of the rows. However, while the sorting and dropping works, when you click on the row, mousedown, and then drag it to another position, the row seems to first "fly in" from the top, rather than originate from the original position on the screen.

While this may seem novel at first, it gets old quite quickly and is clearly a big.

I have never seen this issue before and was wondering if anyone else has any experience.

I am also using [Fuel UX's Wizard](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard), and am unsure whether this is the issue. I have removed the CSS for Fuel UX and the issue remains.

I am also using [jqueryUI bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/), but it seems this CSS has nothing to do with it either.

**JS**

`function sorttable (ID) {
    var mytable = $('#' + ID)
    mytable.find('tbody').sortable({
        update: function(){
            updateorder()
        }
    })
}`

**HTML**

```
<table id="ID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hard to tell without seeing some code ..

Comment: I'd added a screenshot and some pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the CSS won't remove the issue, unless it was all being done with CSS transforms. Posting the actual code somewhere would be ideal, as we could take a look and help identify the real issue. Does the issue remain if you remove the FuelUX wizard entirely from the page?